geometry nodes text follow circle curve n times
hi i want to create a geometry node base text that follows a circle.
The idea is that the text will repeat n times distributed over the curve circle
So that the text extends (like a cylinder outside (outward normals) text on cylinder surface). I don't need the cylinder but that's just as example.
I'm creating some chess pieces as prices that I want to 3d print.
And I like to set our club name around the base n times
Maybe print the winner's name on it or the year and the match, but then that would not require n times that's just once on the front following part of a circle.
I tried it quite a few times but.. i don't get the rotations correctly per letter, strangely I get spirals despite I start with nurbs circles so I do something wrong.

this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3XCoDmw_og might help. good luck.
